# What happens with the ID's of the elements after deletion?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Let's say I have a LinkedList with 20 elements, starting id from 0 to 19. When I remove the first 10 elements from the list, what will be the value of the ids of the remaining 10 elements. Or if remove 5 elements from id 2 to id 7, what will be the ids of the rest of the remaining elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index (not ID) is just the element's position on the list, which changes if elements are added/removed in the middle.

According to do [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int)) for the remove method: "Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (**subtracts one from their indices**)." (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't think of them as ids, they aren't. They're indices in the list, so they get adjusted so as to ensure there are no gaps.

This you could have found out yourself very easily btw, by just trying it.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList implements Deque as well. so when you remove the elements the indexes also get adjusted.